# Why does this conversion of infix to postfix notation using stack as an ADT crash?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stack, postfix-notation, turbo-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 5
struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};
class stack
{
    public:
        node *top;
        stack()         //constructor
        {
            top=NULL;
        }
        char Top()     //return top element without popping
        {
            return(top->data);
        }
        int empty()     //check empty
        {
            if(top==NULL)
                return(1);
            return(0);
        }
        void push(char x)     //push function
        {
            node *p;
            p=new node;
            p->data=x;
            p->next=top;
            top=p;
        }
        char pop()         //pop function
        {
            node *p;
            char x;
            p=top;
            top=top->next;
            x=p->data;
            delete(p);
            return(x);
        }
        int precedence(char x)   //check precedence of operators
        {
            if(x=='(')
                return 0;
            else if(x=='+'||x=='-')
                return 1;
            else if(x=='*'||x=='/'||x=='%')
                return 2;
            return 3;
        }
        void infix_to_postfix(char infix[],char postfix[]);
};
void infix_to_postfix(char infix[],char postfix[])
{
    stack s;
    char x,token;
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=0;infix[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        token=infix[i];
        if(isalnum(token))
            postfix[j++]=token;
        else
            if(token=='(')
                s.push(token);
            else
                if(token==')')
                {
                    while((x=s.pop())!='(')
                        postfix[j++]=x;
                }

                else
                {
                    while(s.precedence(token)<=s.precedence(s.Top())&& !s.empty())
                        postfix[j++]=s.pop();
                    s.push(token);
                }
    }
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        x=s.pop();
        postfix[j++]=x;
    }
    postfix[j++]='\0';
}
int main()
{
    char infix[30],postfix[30];
    cout<<"\nEnter the infix expression::\n";
    cin>>infix;
    infix_to_postfix(infix,postfix);
    cout<<"/nThe equivalent postfix expression is::"<<postfix;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is giving segmentation fault with gedit in Ubuntu...whereas when the same code when run with turbo C in Windows with the required changes as follows...runs correctly...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5
struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
};
class stack
{
    public:
        node *top;
        stack()         //constructor
        {
            top=NULL;
        }
        char Top()     //return top element without popping
        {
            return(top->data);
        }
        int empty()     //check empty
        {
            if(top==NULL)
                return(1);
            return(0);
        }
        void push(char x)     //push function
        {
            node *p;
            p=new node;
            p->data=x;
            p->next=top;
            top=p;
        }
        char pop()         //pop function
        {
            node *p;
            char x;
            p=top;
            top=top->next;
            x=p->data;
            delete(p);
            return(x);
        }
        int precedence(char x)   //check precedence of operators
        {
            if(x=='(')
                return 0;
            else if(x=='+'||x=='-')
                return 1;
            else if(x=='*'||x=='/'||x=='%')
                return 2;
            return 3;
        }
        void infix_to_postfix(char infix[],char postfix[]);
};
void infix_to_postfix(char infix[],char postfix[])
{
    stack s;
    char x,token;
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=0;infix[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        token=infix[i];
        if(isalnum(token))
            postfix[j++]=token;
        else
            if(token=='(')
                s.push(token);
            else
                if(token==')')
                {
                    while((x=s.pop())!='(')
                        postfix[j++]=x;
                }

                else
                {
                    while(s.precedence(token)<=s.precedence(s.Top())&& !s.empty())
                        postfix[j++]=s.pop();
                    s.push(token);
                }
    }
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        x=s.pop();
        postfix[j++]=x;
    }
    postfix[j++]='\0';
}
int main()
{
    char infix[30],postfix[30];
    cout<<"\nEnter the infix expression::\n";
    cin>>infix;
    infix_to_postfix(infix,postfix);
    cout<<"\nEquivalent postfix expression is::"<<postfix;
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

Why is the problem arising in Ubuntu???

Comment: Please try to narrow down the code that reproduces the error. Don't expect people to read all this code and find the problem for you.

Comment: I will all-but-guarantee you the problem isn't with Ubuntu. Since you have Ubuntu however, run it with full debugging symbols through Valgrind. I've every confidence if you're not playing be the defined-behavior rules, you'll know soon enough. And just to completeness, you should post an expression that "succeeds" (I use that term loosely) on Windows, but fails on Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that [tag:turboc++] is a very ancient and outdated compiler that let's you compile silly things without any warning. Did you check for compiler warnings of c++ in ubuntu (whatever toolchain you're using)?

Answer (score 3):

You never check whether your input stack is empty before directly dereferencing `top->data`. Specifically, this loop:

```
  while(s.precedence(token)<=s.precedence(s.Top())&& !s.empty())
        postfix[j++]=s.pop();
  s.push(token);
```

can, and in your case *will*, dereference an empty stack because you check the empty state *after* you've already dereferenced the top pointer via `s.Top()`. You can avoid the inappropriate dereference by using boolean short-circuiting and the proper evaluation order:

```
  while(!s.empty() && s.precedence(token)<=s.precedence(s.Top()))
        postfix[j++]=s.pop();
  s.push(token);
```

**Input**

```
A*(B+C/(D-A))
```

**Output**

> The equivalent postfix expression is::`ABCDA-/+*`

That said, this is *extremely* brittle. Unless specifically instructed to do so there is no reason you shouldn't be using a custom stack in the first place, as the standard adapter `std::stack<>` will remove about 90% of this code, and I strongly suggest taking advantage of that.

Finally, this is flat-out bug. Windows or Ubuntu makes no difference. It invokes undefined behavior. That it didn't crash on Windows means you were lucky (or not, since you assumed it was ok because it didn't crash); not right. And in case you're wondering how I noticed this, I saw it in the code, but confirmed it with Valgrind, which confirmed my suspicion *immediately*.

---

**Using Standard Library for the Heavy Lifting**

This gets considerably simpler when you use classes from the standard library for most of the operations, as you can hopefully see below. I kept your algorithm intact, but just used the `std::stack` adapter and `std::string` classes for the guts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

static int precedence(char x)   //check precedence of operators
{
    if(x=='(')
        return 0;
    else if(x=='+'||x=='-')
        return 1;
    else if(x=='*'||x=='/'||x=='%')
        return 2;
    return 3;
}

std::string infix_to_postfix(const std::string& infix)
{
    std::stack<char> s;
    std::string postfix;

    for (auto ch : infix)
    {
        if (isalnum(ch))
            postfix.push_back(ch);

        else if (ch == '(')
            s.push(ch);

        else if(ch == ')')
        {
            while (!s.empty())
            {
                ch = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (ch == '(')
                    break;
                postfix.push_back(ch);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            while(!s.empty() && precedence(ch)<=precedence(s.top()))
            {
                postfix.push_back(s.top());
                s.pop();
            }
            s.push(ch);
        }
    }

    while(!s.empty())
    {
        postfix.push_back(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }

    return postfix;
}

int main()
{
    const char infix[] = "A*(B+C/(D-A)+2*(E-F))";
    cout << "\nThe equivalent postfix expression is: " << infix_to_postfix(infix);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

> `A*(B+C/(D-A)+2*(E-F))`

**Output**

> The equivalent postfix expression is: `ABCDA-/+2EF-*+*`